# fields_for not nesting attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this form:

```
<%= form_for(:quiz_responses, url: quiz_responses_path) do |f| %>

<%= f.hidden_field :name, value: @survey.name %>

<%= fields_for :questions do |ff| %>
<% @questions.each do |question| %>
<ul> 
<%= ff.hidden_field "#{question_counter}", value: question.content %>
<%= ff.label question.content %>

<%= fields_for :answers do |fff| %>
<% question.answers.each do |answer| %>

<%= fff.hidden_field "#{answer_counter}", value: answer.content %>
<% answer_counter += 1 %>
<%= fff.label answer.content %>

<%= f.radio_button("user_answer[#{user_answer_counter}]", answer.content) %>


<% end #questions.answers.each do %>
<% end #fields_for answers %>
<% user_answer_counter += 1 %>
</ul>
<% question_counter += 1 %>
<% end #@questions.each do %>

<% end #fields_for questions %> 

<%= f.submit %>
<% end #form_for%>
```

My wanted result is that I get a params hash with :quiz_responses containing a :questions hash, and each question value inside that hash contains an :answers hash containing answers. But this is what I see:
[image]

where there's a questions hash containing all the questions and a separate answers hash containing all the answers, and somehow user_answeris inside quiz_responses. How do I fix this mess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `fields_for` on your form object like this:

```
<%= form_for(:quiz_responses, url: quiz_responses_path) do |f| %>

  # ...

  <%= f.fields_for :questions do |ff| %>

  # ...

  <%= ff.fields_for :answers do |fff| %>

  # ...
```

Comment: Right! That fixed the nesting issue. But now all my answers are inside a single question, even though I want only the answers associated with that question to be inside the question. So instead of q1 > 1a,1b,dc,1d, q2> 2a,2b,2c,2d, 1a to 2d are ALL inside q1 and q2 is empty. Like this: http://imgur.com/uadbWU6  

Why is this happening?

Comment: If it helps I defined these before the form_for:  <% question_counter = 0 %>
<% answer_counter = 0 %>
<% user_answer_counter = 0 %>